# Digit to Word conversion in Racket

Tags: recursion, racket, translate, digits

I'm trying to write a program that converts lists of digits (1, 2, 3...etc.) to a list of the corresponding words (One, Two, Three...).  I wrote a helper function that translates individual digits.  It looks like this:

```
(define (translate num)
(cond [(= num 1) 'One]
      [(= num 2) 'Two]
      [(= num 3) 'Three]
      [(= num 4) 'Four]
      [(= num 5) 'Five]
      [(= num 6) 'Six]
      [(= num 7) 'Seven]
      [(= num 8) 'Eight]
      [(= num 9) 'Nine]
      [(= num 0) 'Zero]))
```

That function works.  My function that I call on a list like '(1 2 3) looks like this:

```
(define (translate-digits aList)
 (cond [(empty? aList) '()]
       [else (cons (translate (first aList))
                   (translate (first (rest aList))))] ))
```

It is not working.  I think it has to do with the cons.  But when I test the input '(1 3 5 7) I get '(One . Three).  What's going on?

Comment: I'm wondering, are you working through How to Design Programs learning the design recipe? If you are, you should compare your code to the template; that should show you what's wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using recursion, you're just calling your `translate` function twice instead of calling `translate-digits` and using recursion.

Notice the slight difference:

```
(define (translate-digits aList)
 (cond [(empty? aList) '()]
       [else (cons (translate (first aList))
                   (translate-digits (rest aList)))]))
```

By calling `translate-digits` on the `rest` of the list, you walk down until you hit the empty list and exit out by returning an empty list.